# Trying to center a logo within a div for a fluid gridresponsive websitesite

Tags: css, html

I'm exploring responsive web design and i've encountered a stumbling block.

I have a logo placed at the top of my fluid grid responsive site and I am trying to center the image within the div, not centering the div itself. I'm tring to do this because in smartphone and tablet view, the logo looks good (no need to be centered as it takes up the entire area) but in desktop view the logo is left aligned.

Just want logo to be centered with the div.

html:

```
<div class="gridContainer clearfix">
<div id="logo">
    <img src="images/logo.gif" alt="logo" class="center">
</div>
```

css:

```
img.center {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
#logo {
    clear: both;
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
```

I also have a global img styling in css:

```
img {
    padding: 10px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I've tried so many online solutions, but no luck. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You want to add `text-align: center;` to your `gridContainer` class. E.g.,

```css
.gridContainer {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```
<div class="gridContainer clearfix">
    <div id="logo">
        <img src="..." alt="logo" class="center"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

If `.gridContainer` contains other children that should not be centered, you can add a wrapper `<div>` for the logo with a class containing `text-align: center;`. E.g.,

```css
.gridCenter {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```
<div class="gridContainer clearfix">
    <div class="gridCenter">
        <div id="logo">
            <img src="..." alt="logo" class="center"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

Full example:

```css
#img {
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}
#img.center {
  display: inline-block;
  /*margin-left: auto;*/ /* <-- Not needed. */
  /*margin-right: auto;*/ /* <-- Not needed. */
}

#logo {
  clear: both;
  /*margin: auto;*/ /* <-- Not needed. */
  max-width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

.gridContainer {
  text-align: center;
}

/* Extra styles to display example. */
.gridContainer {
  background: #999;
}
#logo {
  background: #0F0;
}
#img {
  background: #F00;
}
```

```html
<div class="gridContainer clearfix">
  <div id="logo">
    <span id="img" class="center">Logo</span>
  </div>
</div>
```